# Knowing the distribution of $X$, what is the distribution function of $Y:= X(X-1)$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

Let $X$ be exponentially distributed with parameter $1$ and let $Y := X(X-1)$.

Determine the distribution function $F_Y$ of $Y$.

I know that I need to calculate as follows:
$ F_Y(t) = P[Y \leq t] = P[X(X-1) \leq t] = P[X^2-X \leq t]$.

I also know that $F_X(t) = 1-e^{-t}$ for $t \geq 0$, since $X$ is exponentially distributed with parameter $1$.

However, I don't know where to go from there.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Since $X^2-X$ is quadratic, the inequality $X^2-X \le t$ can be solved to $a(t) \le X \le b(t)$ (for $t$ not too small, otherwise the inequality has no solution).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
X(X-1) = X^2-X = X^2 - 2\cdot X\cdot \frac{1}{2} + \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 = \left(X-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-\frac{1}{4} \Rightarrow
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
F_Y(t) &= \Pr\left(Y \leq t\right) = \Pr\left(X(X-1) \leq t\right) = \Pr\left(\left(X-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-\frac{1}{4} \leq t\right) =  \Pr\left(\left(X-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\leq t + \frac{1}{4}\right) = \\
&=\left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
0, & t < -\frac{1}{4} \\
\Pr\left(\left|X-\frac{1}{2}\right|\leq \sqrt{t + \frac{1}{4}}\right), & t \geq -\frac{1}{4}
\end{array}
\right. = \\
&=\left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
0, & t < -\frac{1}{4} \\
\Pr\left(\frac{1}{2} - \sqrt{t + \frac{1}{4}} \leq X \leq \frac{1}{2} + \sqrt{t + \frac{1}{4}}\right), & t \geq -\frac{1}{4}
\end{array}
\right. = \\
&=\left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
0, & t < -\frac{1}{4} \\
F_X\left(\frac{1}{2} + \sqrt{t + \frac{1}{4}}\right) - F_X\left(\frac{1}{2} - \sqrt{t + \frac{1}{4}}\right), & t \geq -\frac{1}{4}
\end{array}
\right. = \\
\end{aligned}
$$

where $F_X(x)$ is a probability distribution function of $X$.

Comment: That should be an intersection, rather than a union.  $\lvert a\rvert\leq b$ exactly when $-b\leq a\leq b$

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right! Thank you for pointing this out. I have fixed the issue.